# ListView ItemSource and RaisePropertyChanged not wroking when adding new items to the list

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, binding

I have a ListView with some items in:

```
 private List<string> _ItemsList;
 public List<string> ItemsList
 {
     get
     {
         return _ItemsList;
     }
     set
     {
         _ItemsList = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("ItemsList");
     }
 }
```

And on my xaml page this:

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}" />
```

When the page is loaded all items are shown in the ListView but when I do ItemsList.AddRange(ItemsList2); all items from ItemsList are added to ItemsList but they are not shown on the xamlpage :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead. That has implemented support for notifying (via interface [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)) the UI about changes to it.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _ItemsList;
public ObservableCollection<string> ItemsList
{
  get
  {
     return _ItemsList;
  }
  set
  {
     _ItemsList = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged("ItemsList");
  }
}
```